# Print something every 10 loop iterations

Tags: php, loops, while-loop, echo

I need to print something in a loop everytime a number is 10, 20, 30, 40...

It should only print once and then continue the loop and print again when the number is divisible by 10.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
    if ($i % 10 == 0) echo $i."\n";
    // do something
}
```

Generally the [modulus operator](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) (%) is what you need here. It calculates the remainder of a division. So: 7 % 5 = 2 and 18 % 5 = 3.